# Getting exceptions when trying to open a serial port

Tags: c#, bluetooth

I am connected to a Bluetooth device (ELM327 OBDII Dongle) and I was able to successfully communicate with it using Tera Term, which seems to be opening a serial port to handle communication. Now I'm trying to write my own program to communicate with the device. I'm able to connect via Bluetooth to the device, but I am having trouble opening the serial port using the following code (COM3 is hard coded right now, but it's one of the ports found using the GetPortNames method):

```
private SerialPort serialPort;
string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
foreach (string p in ports)
    UIWriteLine(p);
serialPort = new SerialPort("COM3");
serialPort.Open();
```

When I call the Open method, I get the following exception which seems to have nothing to do with serial ports:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in System.dll
>
> Additional information: You were not connected because a duplicate name exists on the network. If joining a domain, go to System in Control Panel to change the computer name and try again. If joining a workgroup, choose another workgroup name.

Additionally, when I call the constructor of the serial port and pass in the port name, debugging shows me that many members of my instance of the serial port have thrown exceptions:

> BaseStream = 'serialPort.BaseStream' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

> BreakState = 'serialPort.BreakState' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

> BytesToRead = 'serialPort.BytesToRead' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

etc… They are all `InvalidOperationException`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure that COM3 is not used or open by someone else ? or try to set the baudrate, databits, stopbits, and parity.

Comment: I have also tried calling serialPort.Close() right before attempting to open it, which gave me the same results, but I have not yet tried setting all of the parameters. The baudrate appears to have already been set, but how do I set the other three?

Comment: As you can see here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.open(v=vs.110).aspx there is an exception IOException :The port is in an invalid state. - or - An attempt to set the state of the underlying port failed. For example, the parameters passed from this SerialPort object were invalid.

Comment: Are you accidentally opening it twice?  The second attempt would fail.    Maybe you opened it and never closed it.

Comment: Use the constructor of SerialPort to set baudrate,stopbits,etc... : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z8d1ykfs(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What does UIWriteLine do?

Comment: UIWriteLine simply appends text and Environment.NewLine to a property bound to a text box